# Why do I get a "io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt

I have a problem with my Spring Security JWT Application. I am getting an error because my JWT is expired, but I can't find, where it gets the 2022-04-12 as an expiration date. I can't find a single piece of code, which says that the expiration date is the 2022-04-12. After my understanding, it is creating a new token, each time I am logging in with a new expiration time, which also has to be true, because in my output I get a new token everytime. But because the 2022-04-12 has already passed, I am getting a "io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException". So where does it get the 2022-04-12 from???
I am just providing the parts of my code, I think are neccesary, but if you need more code, just let me know!( I am using Spring Security, if that matters)

Filter:

```
package de.gabriel.springsecurityjwt.filters;


import de.gabriel.springsecurityjwt.services.MyUserDetailsService;
import de.gabriel.springsecurityjwt.util.JwtUtil;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwt = null;

        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
           if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) { // If token is valid
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);

          }

        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Util class for JWT:

```
package de.gabriel.springsecurityjwt.util;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

@Service
public class JwtUtil { // JwtUtil is a class that is used to create and parse JWT tokens

    private final String SECRET_KEY = "secret";

    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }
    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET_KEY).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return createToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
    }

    private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {
        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 10))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, SECRET_KEY).compact();
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUsername(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }
}
```

Rest Controller class:

```
package de.gabriel.springsecurityjwt;

import de.gabriel.springsecurityjwt.models.AuthenticationRequest;
import de.gabriel.springsecurityjwt.models.AuthenticationResponse;
import de.gabriel.springsecurityjwt.services.MyUserDetailsService;
import de.gabriel.springsecurityjwt.util.JwtUtil;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Date;

@RestController
public class HelloResource {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @RequestMapping( "/hello" )
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {

        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword())
            );
        }
        catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new Exception("Incorrect username or password", e);
        }


        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService
                .loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());

        final String jwt = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthenticationResponse(jwt)); // Return token

    }

}
```

Security Configurer class:

```
package de.gabriel.springsecurityjwt;

import de.gabriel.springsecurityjwt.filters.JwtRequestFilter;
import de.gabriel.springsecurityjwt.services.MyUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().
                anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
                httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

}
```

Here is the error log:

```
io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException: JWT expired at 2022-04-12T21:27:05Z. Current time: 2022-04-14T22:20:23Z, a difference of 175998276 milliseconds.  Allowed clock skew: 0 milliseconds.
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:385) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:481) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:541) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at de.gabriel.springsecurityjwt.util.JwtUtil.extractAllClaims(JwtUtil.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at de.gabriel.springsecurityjwt.util.JwtUtil.extractClaim(JwtUtil.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at de.gabriel.springsecurityjwt.util.JwtUtil.extractUsername(JwtUtil.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at de.gabriel.springsecurityjwt.filters.JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtRequestFilter.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

This is the token used:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJmb28iLCJleHAiOjE2NTAwMDIyOTEsImlhdCI6MTY0OTk2NjI5MX0.tzfB0Wy9Dp3Y9pl-5_Oc4gwPClOHlIjE8kHUcgvKhUs
```

And this is the token (payload) decoded:

```
{
  "sub": "foo",
  "exp": 1650002291, (2022-04-15)
  "iat": 1649966291
}
```

This is a
[image of the decoded JWT from jwt.io](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsxsb.png)

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy90I.png) this is the request I use

Comment: Is the clock on the machine you're running this on incorrect?  The token expiration date (April 14, 2022 at 23:58:11) hasn't passed even as I write this.

Comment: @stdunbar Where do you see this expiration date? If this would be the expiration date it would work, but in the error log it says, that the expiration date was the 2022-04-12, and not the 2022-04-14 :/

Comment: If I paste your token into [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) the `exp` field is April 14, 2022 at 23:58:11 and these are always UTC.  UTC, as of writing this, is April 14, 2022 21:13 and a bit.

Comment: @stdunbar Oh yeah right. I even get the day of tomorrow(2022-04-15). But thats how it should be, right? I want the token to run out tomorrow so I can test it now, but as you can see in the error log(JWT expired at 2022-04-12T21:27:05Z) the token has expired at the April 12th. And this is the part I don't understand. As you said, the token hasn't even expired yet(after the info in the payload) but after the error log the token has expired at the 12th of April. And now I wan't to know why it doesn't expire tomorrow but expired 2(3) days prior?

Comment: @stdunbar "The "exp" (expiration time) claim identifies the expiration time on or after which the JWT MUST NOT be accepted for processing. The processing of the "exp" claim requires **that the current date/time MUST be before the expiration date/time listed in the "exp" claim.**" - https://gist.github.com/soulmachine/b368ce7292ddd7f91c15accccc02b8df So if it would be like it is standing in the token(even you said, that you see a date that hasn't even passed yet on jwt.io), everything should work. But somehow JWT gets a weird date from somewhere I don't know and uses that

Comment: I feel like there is a mismatch somewhere.   The error doesn't have the same time as what you posted, regardless of the date and time zone.  The posted JWT is XX:58:11.  Your error is XX:27:05.  I'd re-verify that you're really using the token you posted.

Comment: @stdunbar Yes, that correct. The expiration time in the error log is another one, then in the token. And that is the problem! I have the same question as you: Where does this time come from? Because it doesn't come from the token. Now I also posted a picture of the request, where you can see the same token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a mistake, while sending the request in Postman. Instead of passing the JWT in the Header I passed it as an Parameter, which of course won't work because I have nothing that extracts the JWT from the URL‍♂️